# Is there a way to minimize/detach a Workbook window while leaving the program up?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am wondering if it's possible to manipulate the size of a workbook window while still leaving Excel up. I have a Userform and I want the workbook to basically be detached and moved around like a separate window inside the program with a Userform in the middle.

I've seen it done in earlier versions; the background is completely grey (like how some programs have the Minimize, Maximize and Close for the program and a separate set for individual windows) with the toolbar and everything still at the top; the workbook window is at the bottom or to the side. It seems in Excel 2016, any manipulation of the Workbook window minimizes the entire program every time.

When I try to accomplish this with Vertical or Horizontal windows, etc., I can't get a blank Excel window opened. Is this possible in the newer versions?

Comment: This question belongs on [su].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel (since Office 2013) is now an SDI (single document interface) implementation: prior to that it was MDI (multiple document interface).  You'd need an MDI Excel version to do what you seem to be looking for.

See:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/programming-for-the-single-document-interface-in-excel

Comment: That's rather unfortunate, but it was exactly what I was asking about. Thank you.